# pg_query(): Query failed: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected in php script

Tags: php, postgresql, apache, postgresql-9.3

After reading several posts (I read an issue with OpenSSL but did not understand how to solve this error), I have not found any solutions to this issue. I understand that it is a connection failure of the postgresql database. It is not clear to me, though, why this happens in my laptop, I am working internally (localhost level) so it should be no problem at all. In fact, some time ago this worked before in my laptop, perhaps some software upgrading changed things. Nevertheless, this is what I get:

```
Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected in /mnt/windowsd/WEBs/php/pg.php on line 293
An SQL error occured.
```

Line 293 refers to:

```
292 # Try query or error
293 $rs = pg_query($conn, $sql);
294 if (!$rs) {
295     echo "An SQL error occured.\n";
296     exit;
297 }
```

and variable `$conn` is:

```
 9 # connect to PostgreSQL database
 10 $conn = pg_connect("user='aaaa' password='aaaa' dbname='aaaa' host='localhost'");
 11 if (!$conn) {
 12     echo "Not connected : " . pg_error();
 13     exit;
 14 }
```

How can I solve this SSL SYSCALL error?

Any hints are appreciated.

System:

```
ii  postgresql-9.3                                              9.3.24-0ubuntu0.14.04                                amd64        object-relational SQL database, version 9.3 server
ii  postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.2                                  2.2.2+dfsg-2~trusty1                                 amd64        Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 9.3
ii  postgresql-9.3-postgis-scripts                              2.2.2+dfsg-2~trusty1                                 all          Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 9.3 -- scripts
ii  postgresql-client-9.3                                       9.3.24-0ubuntu0.14.04                                amd64        front-end programs for PostgreSQL 9.3
ii  postgresql-client-common                                    154ubuntu1.1                                         all          manager for multiple PostgreSQL client versions
ii  postgresql-common                                           154ubuntu1.1                                         all          PostgreSQL database-cluster manager
ii  postgresql-contrib-9.3                                      9.3.24-0ubuntu0.14.04                                amd64        additional facilities for PostgreSQL
ii  libapache2-mod-php5                                         5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.27                               amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
ii  php5                                                        5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.27                               all          server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
ii  php5-cgi                                                    5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.27                               amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (CGI binary)
ii  php5-cli                                                    5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.27                               amd64        command-line interpreter for the php5 scripting language
ii  php5-common                                                 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.27                               amd64        Common files for packages built from the php5 source
ii  php5-curl                                                   5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.27                               amd64        CURL module for php5
ii  php5-dev                                                    5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.26                               amd64        Files for PHP5 module development
ii  php5-fpm                                                    5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.27                               amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
ii  php5-json                                                   1.3.2-2build1                                        amd64        JSON module for php5
ii  php5-pgsql                                                  5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.27                               amd64        PostgreSQL module for php5
ii  apache2                                                     2.4.7-1ubuntu4.21                                    amd64        Apache HTTP Server
ii  apache2-bin                                                 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.21                                    amd64        Apache HTTP Server (binary files and modules)
ii  apache2-data                                                2.4.7-1ubuntu4.21                                    all          Apache HTTP Server (common files)
ii  apache2-dev                                                 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.21                                    amd64        Apache HTTP Server (development headers)
ii  apache2-mpm-prefork                                         2.4.7-1ubuntu4.21                                    amd64        transitional prefork MPM package for apache2
ii  apache2-mpm-worker                                          2.4.7-1ubuntu4.21                                    amd64        transitional worker MPM package for apache2
ii  apache2-utils                                               2.4.7-1ubuntu4.21                                    amd64        Apache HTTP Server (utility programs for web servers)
ii  libapache2-mod-auth-pgsql                                   2.0.3-6ubuntu0.1                                     amd64        Module for Apache2 which provides PostgreSQL authentication
ii  libapache2-mod-fastcgi                                      2.4.7~0910052141-1.1                                 amd64        Apache 2 FastCGI module for long-running CGI scripts
ii  libapache2-mod-mapcache                                     1.6.1-1~trusty0                                      amd64        tile caching server - Apache module
ii  libapache2-mod-php5                                         5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.27                               amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
ii  globus-openssl-module-progs                                 3.3-2                                                amd64        Globus Toolkit - Globus OpenSSL Module Wrapper Programs
ii  lcmaps-openssl-interface                                    1.6.1-2                                              all          LCMAPS header files for OpenSSL interfaces
ii  libcrypt-openssl-bignum-perl                                0.04-4build1                                         amd64        Perl module to access OpenSSL multiprecision integer arithmetic libraries
ii  libcrypt-openssl-dsa-perl                                   0.14-1                                               amd64        module which implements the DSA signature verification system
ii  libcrypt-openssl-random-perl                                0.04-1build6                                         amd64        Access to the OpenSSL pseudo-random number generator
ii  libcrypt-openssl-rsa-perl                                   0.28-1build1                                         amd64        module for RSA encryption using OpenSSL
ii  libcrypt-openssl-x509-perl                                  1.8.4-1                                              amd64        Perl extension to OpenSSL's X509 API
ii  libcurl4-openssl-dev:amd64                                  7.35.0-1ubuntu2.20                                   amd64        development files and documentation for libcurl (OpenSSL flavour)
ii  libengine-pkcs11-openssl                                    0.1.8-3                                              amd64        OpenSSL engine for PKCS#11 modules
ii  libevent-openssl-2.0-5:amd64                                2.0.21-stable-1ubuntu1.14.04.2                       amd64        Asynchronous event notification library (openssl)
ii  libglobus-gsi-openssl-error-dbg:amd64                       2.1-5                                                amd64        Globus Toolkit - Globus OpenSSL Error Handling Debug Symbols
ii  libglobus-gsi-openssl-error-dev:amd64                       2.1-5                                                amd64        Globus Toolkit - Globus OpenSSL Error Handling Development Files
ii  libglobus-gsi-openssl-error-doc                             2.1-5                                                all          Globus Toolkit - Globus OpenSSL Error Handling Documentation Files
ii  libglobus-gsi-openssl-error0:amd64                          2.1-5                                                amd64        Globus Toolkit - Globus OpenSSL Error Handling
ii  libglobus-openssl-module-dbg:amd64                          3.3-2                                                amd64        Globus Toolkit - Globus OpenSSL Module Wrapper Debug Symbols
ii  libglobus-openssl-module-dev:amd64                          3.3-2                                                amd64        Globus Toolkit - Globus OpenSSL Module Wrapper Development Files
ii  libglobus-openssl-module-doc                                3.3-2                                                all          Globus Toolkit - Globus OpenSSL Module Wrapper Documentation Files
ii  libglobus-openssl-module0:amd64                             3.3-2                                                amd64        Globus Toolkit - Globus OpenSSL Module Wrapper
ii  libgnutls-openssl27:amd64                                   2.12.23-12ubuntu2.8                                  amd64        GNU TLS library - OpenSSL wrapper
ii  libpathfinder-openssl-1                                     1.1.3-0.4                                            amd64        Pathfinder integration Library for OpenSSL
ii  libxmlsec1-openssl                                          1.2.18-2ubuntu1                                      amd64        Openssl engine for the XML security library
ii  openssl                                                     1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.27                                   amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - cryptographic utility
ii  openssl-blacklist                                           0.5-3                                                all          Blacklists for  OpenSSL RSA keys and tools
ii  openssl-blacklist-extra                                     0.5-3                                                all          Non-default blacklists of OpenSSL RSA keys
ii  python-openssl                                              0.13-2ubuntu6                                        amd64        Python 2 wrapper around the OpenSSL library
ii  python-openssl-dbg                                          0.13-2ubuntu6                                        amd64        Python 2 wrapper around the OpenSSL library (debug extension)
ii  python-openssl-doc                                          0.13-2ubuntu6                                        all          Python wrapper around the OpenSSL library (documentation package)
ii  python3-openssl                                             0.13-2ubuntu6                                        amd64        Python 3 wrapper around the OpenSSL library
ii  python3-openssl-dbg                                         0.13-2ubuntu6                                        amd64        Python 3 wrapper around the OpenSSL library (debug extension)
ii  strongswan-plugin-openssl                                   5.1.2-0ubuntu2.11                                    amd64        strongSwan plugin for OpenSSL
```